# Insert pdf image in latex

Tags: graphics

When I try to insert image like this

```
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}
{
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\lhead{} \chead{} \rhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.05,trim ={0.25mm 0.25mm 0.25mm 0.25mm},clip=true]{mylogo.pdf}}
\lfoot{} \cfoot{\thepage} \rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.35 pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0 pt}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
```

it just wont work, and I

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

I just got logo.pdf text on that place and small little rectangle

I have this

```
%%HEADER
\fancypagestyle{mystil}
{
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\lhead{} \chead{} \rhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.05,trim ={0.25mm 0.25mm 0.25mm 0.25mm},clip=true]{logo.pdf}}
\lfoot{} \cfoot{\thepage} \rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.35 pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0 pt}
}
\pagestyle{mystil}
```

and this on new page

```
\newpage
\pagestyle{mystil}
```

Answer (score 2):

This MWE here:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}
{
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\lhead{} \chead{} \rhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.05,trim ={0.25mm 0.25mm 0.25mm 0.25mm},clip=true]{example-image}}
\lfoot{} \cfoot{\thepage} \rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.35 pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0 pt}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

works as expected:

[image]

See why preparing a fully working [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) is so important?

Probably in the process of preparing it, you will be able to find the error --- it happened a lot of times to me. And without it, we can't guess the origin of the problem.

Comment: hahah, idk why won't work at me - maybe miktex need a few compiling :D 
about which braces You're talking?

Comment: ---sorry, wrong comment ;-). From your description you probably had a `draft` option somewhere...

Comment: np, how can i fix that? haha

Comment: @amygdala27 I can't help without a fully compilable code, sorry. (I suppose idk means I do know, can't understand "np").